# Filter objects using relationship not querying whole DB in Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two related objects: Post and Comment. One Post can have many Comments. Im using backref so I can reference comment list from post object:

```py
post = Post.query.get(post_id)
all_comments = post.comments # returns all comments of whole post
```

Now I want to filter those comments by their author. I want to be able to do something like this:

```py
post.comments.filter(author_id=author_id)
```

In Django I did it like this:

```py
post.comments.all().filter(author_id=author_id)
```

But in Flask I can't figure it out. I don't to query all database using:

```py
Comment.query.filter_by(post_id=post_id, author_id=author_id)
```

How do I do that query?

Comment: what do you mean by this author_id=author_id?

Comment: It's not pretty but it's the same thing, you're still querying "all the database" in Django. Just make sure that your Comment tables has indexes on both post_id and author_id

Comment: have you tried `post.comments.filter_by(author_id=author_id)`?

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni Get all comments that were created by person of id equal author_id, because post can have multiple comments created by different users.

Comment: @lalithkumar yes, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

```
Comment.query.join(Post, Comment.post_id == Post.id).filter_by(Post.post_id=post_id, Comment.author_id=author_id).all()
```